# how can I increase the value of my article in another model view for example in django

Tags: django

So here, I would like the quantity existing of my Article model to increase when saving the Purchase model,
Here is my code in views.py that does not work!
I am still a beginner in Django. thank you in advance

example:
quantity of article in stock: 20
quantity purchased during a purchase: 5
so in the end in the database I would like to have 25 in the item warren in stock!
sorry for my english, i use google translator

```
def achat_form_view(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = AchatForm(request.POST,error_class=ParagraphErrorList)
        if form.is_valid():
            Article.quantite = Article.quantite + Achat.quantite_a
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('manapoitra_achat')
    else:
        form = AchatForm()
    return render(request, 'achatH.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py :

```
class Achat(models.Model):
    id_article_a = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_fournisseur_a = models.ForeignKey(Fournisseur, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantite_a = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=4, verbose_name="Quantité(s)")
    date_a = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date de création")
    date_save_tara_a = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pk+' achat'

class Article(models.Model):
    photo = models.FileField()
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name="Produit")
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, verbose_name="Type", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categorie = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, verbose_name="Catégorie", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prix_de_vente = models.CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name="Prix de vente")
    prix_d_achat = models.CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name="Prix d'achat")
    quantite = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=4, verbose_name="Quantité(s)")
    date_a = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Date de création")
    date_de_perim = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Perimé(e) le")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

Comment: But what is the "value" here? Is `quantite` a field on Article? If so how are you determining *which* Article is to have its quantity increased? You should probably show your model and form definitions.

Comment: Don't put code in the comments, edit the question and post it there, properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that Achat and Article refer to the entire class, not any specific instance. What you want to do is take the Achat created by your form, and increase the quantity of the specific Article chosen in that form. You can do this via the return value of `form.save()`, which is an instance of Achat.

```
if form.is_valid():
    achat = form.save()
    article = achat.id_article_a
    article.quantite += achat.quantite_a
    article.save()
    return redirect('manapoitra_achat')
```

(Note, your field naming convention is very strange; there's no need to suffix with `_a`, but more importantly you should not name ForeignKey fields with an `id_` prefix; the Django ForeignKey is *not* an ID, but gives you access directly to the related object. So for example `id_article_a` should be just `article`.)

Comment: Thanks that to work!
I did not find how to do this after several documentation! but if that does not bother you, where can I find a tutorial that learns what you did there?

Comment: Does it work too if I use the operator - = ? and how to make the condition so that it does not take a negative value? thank you